# What is the constant in $F=kma$ called?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, terminology, units, dimensional-analysis

I understand fully where the constant comes from and why it is defined as $k=1\ \text{N}\ \text{kg}^{-1}\ \text{m}^{-1}\ \text{s}^2$

But does it have an official name?

If I were to give it a name I suppose I would maybe call it one of the following:

- Constant of inertial mass
- The inertia constant
- Newton's constant of inertia
- Newton's 2nd law constant

Comment: "The definition of the newton"

Comment: Since you are using the SI system of units, $k$ is not just numerically 1, but it is also dimensionless. In other words, since the newton is **defined** as kg · m/s^2, the units in your expression for $k$ cancel out completely. So, $k =1$, with no units.

Answer (score 2):

It is sometimes called a *definitional constant*, but this term may not be universally understood. See for instance [1].

[1] T. Quinn, [Physical quantities](https://books.google.it/books?id=DAzvAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&dq=definitional+constant&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjilo3Vv7bqAhVCi8MKHSnICU0Q6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=definitional%20constant&f=false), in *Metrology and Fundamental Constants*, *Proceedings of the International School of Physics "Enrico Fermi"*, Course CLXVI, 2007.

Answer (score 1):

It's built in to the definition of the newton.

If the newton is defined as "the force that produces 1 m/s<sup>2</sup> acceleration when acting on 1 kg" then clearly no further constant of proportionality is required in the formula $F=ma$ .

If you're working in some other unit system, the unit of force will be defined similarly to avoid the need for any further scaling factor in this formula.

Answer (score 0):

The proportionality constant to Newtons second law is defined as the *mass*. There is no 'k'. It's just $f\propto a \implies f = M a$ where M is some constant of proportionality.

Comment: Wow , I never thought about mass like that before. Really interesting.

Comment: I don't think this correct at all. $M$ **is not a constant** and really $f\propto a$ AND $f\propto M$, so $f\propto Ma$.

Comment: You’re right, mass doesn’t have to be constant. Just like for any proportionality it doesn’t have to be constant. 

E.g. a spring has a spring constant k which is the constant of proportionality. But you can *change* the spring constant if you use another sprint, or deform your original one. 

It’s just that we define that constant based on the proportionality. So even though it can change, the relationship is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Closest analog to your expression would be relativistic Newton second law :

$$ F = \gamma ma \tag 1,$$

where $$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \tag 2$$

is called Lorentz factor, but it's **unitless** variable, as is seen from square root.

Point of (1) is to illustrate that when object speed approaches $c$ you need bigger and bigger force for supplying *constant* (even tiny) acceleration.

Comment: Why would you call $\gamma$ a *constant*? In all nontrivial situations (i.e. those where the net force $F$ is nonzero), $\gamma$  will *not* be constant.

Comment: Yes, it's a variable. Changed into "variable" to be precise. English is not my native language, so maybe sometimes upon "rushing to answer" my translation module in brains starts glitching ;-D Or maybe Alzheimer's disease kicks-in slowly (my aunt has died due to Alzheimer's disease, and late-onset Alzheimer's is about 70% heritable, so I'm afraid of this like hell).

Comment: Sorry to hear that, that does sound scary! Back to the question, though: I don't think this answer fits at all. It really should feature a true constant.

Comment: I think this answer gives a good example of a related but different issue than what the OP strictly asked. In the OP's question, the constant $k$ can be set to $1$ by the choice of units (as others have said); in other words, there is nothing fundamental about $k$, but it simply depends on conventions. On the other hand, the $\gamma$ appearing in this answer cannot be rescaled away by a choice of units since it is not a simple constant, and therefore is something more fundamental.

Comment: @Andrew I would think that starting with your second sentence, you have laid out a convincing argument that the issues are **un**related?

Comment: To put more fuel into the fire, IMHO constant and variable does not differ very much conceptually.  I like Dirac words "_A physical constant in quantum mechanics may thus be looked upon [...] as an observable with a single eigenvalue_". So to say, constant -> 1 possible output, variable : $\gt 1$ outputs (omitting errors of course). In addition, nobody has proved yet, that our beloved constants like electric charge $e$ or $c$ or $h$ will never change or evolve with time passing by in a universe. So what is constant today- tomorrow may be not.

Comment: This is a part of a bigger problem,- How do we know that currently accepted fundamental laws of Physics are **truly fundamental** or just "a temporary wish" by a current state of things in a universe ? Maybe after 1 billion billion years, fundamental laws will be different than now ? Or maybe if somebody would "rolled back" time and repeated the BigBang,- outcomes and laws would be different that we have now ? These are very deep questions for which I believe nobody has decent answers (yet) ...